# How to remove the background screen which is from Screen A of another stack in Screen C of another stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have the following stack navigator.

Navigation Container

```
const ContentStack = createStackNavigator();

<NavigationContainer>
    <ContentStack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="SceeenAStack"
      headerMode="float"
      screenOptions={{
        header: props => {
          return <CustomHeader {...props} />;
        },
      }}>
          <ContentStack.Screen name="SceeenAStack" component={TabA} />
          <ContentStack.Screen name="ScreenBStack" component={TabB} />
    </ContentStack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Nested Stack1

```
const SceeenAStack = createStackNavigator();

<SceeenAStack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="ScreenA"
      headerMode="none"
      screenOptions={{
        gestureEnabled: true,
      }}>

        <SceeenAStack.Screen
           name="ScreenA"
           component={ScreenA}
        />
        <SceeenAStack.Screen
           name="ScreenB"
           component={ScreenB}
        />

</SceeenAStack.Navigator>
```

Nested Stack2

```
const ScreenBStack = createStackNavigator();

<ScreenBStack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="ScreenC"
      headerMode="none"
      screenOptions={{
        gestureEnabled: true,
      }}>

        <ScreenBStack.Screen
           name="ScreenA"
           component={ScreenC}
        />
        <ScreenBStack.Screen
           name="ScreenB"
           component={ScreenD}
        />

</ScreenBStack.Navigator>
```

The screen(Body) of screenA is of SceeenAStack is getting displayed in background in ScreenB of SceeenBStack.

How can I remove it?

Here is the screenshot:

[image: ScreenA of ScreenAStack]
[image: ScreenC of ScreenBStack]

> Note The icon coming in the background is not part of the header of ScreenA.

Comment: This component which is circled in red im assuming is only in Screen A ?

Comment: Yes its only in screen A

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `navigate()` or `push()` in this case. Use `replace()`

example from the docs:

```
 import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch({
  ...StackActions.replace('Profile', {
    user: 'jane',
  }),
  source: route.key,
});
```

Comment: Will try this solution